# How to disable a mat-button-toggle in an Angular reactive form via code

Tags: javascript, angular, disable, react-forms

I'm trying to find out how to programmatically disable/enable a `<mat-button-toggle>` in a reactive Angular form, can anyone help?

This is the group in the html and ts file snippets;

```js
export class PComponent implements OnInit {
    pForm: FormGroup;
    pOptions: FormControl;
    pInsertOption: FormControl;

    constructor( ) {
        this.pForm = new FormGroup({
            pName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
            
            pOptions: new FormControl('insert'),
            pInsertOption: new FormControl(),
            pDeleteOption: new FormControl(),
            pReplaceOption: new FormControl()
        });
        
     this.pForm.get('pName').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
            if (val != '') {
                this.pForm.get('pInsertOption').disable();
            }
            else this.pForm.get('pInsertOption').enable();
        });
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="pForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

<mat-button-toggle-group p formControlName="pOptions" aria-label="P Options">
    <mat-button-toggle id="pInsertOption" value="insert">Insert</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle id="pDeleteOption" value="delete">Delete</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle id="pReplaceOption" value="replace">Replace</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>

</form>
```

But the toggle isn't affected.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you written a `[formGroup]` directive in one of the parents of this control ?

Comment: Hi @MGX, yes I did

Comment: For anyone looking at this; I now realise that mat-button-toggle doesn't have an interface which allows for this form of interaction... so I've taken an alternative approach using boolean variables and binding the [disabled] properties of these.

Comment: Hm yes it does, it implements control value accessor, so it behaves like a form control.

Comment: Hi @MGX when I tried formControlName="pInsertOption" and in ts pInsertOption: new FormControl(), I got error stating that the control was not recognised;

Comment: ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'pInsertOption'

Comment: Hi @MGX, I probably didn't explain myself precisely enough - is there a means to achieve the above? I suspect it has something to do with that control being nested inside the <mat-button-toggle-group>?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] of your issue for me to help you unfortunately